is there a utility to open pjw files?
I'm using IDEC's WinLDR program to program PLCs in wine.
works great, but this is not the goal, what I have is 30 some years of PLC programs to convert to C. The program output is fileName.pjw
which is shown as an archive type, but in the package manager I don't see a way to extract this particular file type.
Is there a utility for extracting IDEC's pjw files?
Im on Jammy if that is necessary.
from the command line:
$ file project01.pjw
project01.pjw: gzip compressed data, from TOPS/20, original size modulo 2^32 314621
gunzip wont decompress it though, unrecognized extenstion

What does file fileName.pjw tell you? In Unix/Linux, the extension (.pjw) is not related to the file's content. Please [edit] your Question to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by both current and future readers (who have better answers).  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.

try opening it with 7zip

Geuss I forgot to run the file command, and investigate what linux thinks this file is.
From file command:
$ file project01.pjw 
project01.pjw: gzip compressed data, from TOPS/20, original size modulo 2^32 314621

Tried a gunzip -d project.pjw but it reported unknown extension.
so then I wrote a python script to do it:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import gzip
import shutil

input_file = 'project01.pjw'
output_file = 'project01'

with gzip.open(input_file, 'rb') as f_in:
    with open(output_file, 'wb') as f_out:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)

ok cool, that produces a decompressed project01 file.
there is some binary data embedded, but there is program file data in plain text, XML data.

Or: gzip -d < project01.pjw > project01

@muru .... I didnt understand that the brackets were part of the command, I thought those were placeholders or something like how they are in other manpages.

Those are redirections - < for input, > for output.

After a quick google:
WindLDR (PLC Ladder programming tool) obviously creates files with pjw extension.
The quickie revealed that these contain all data in a project.
The format is most likely not documented for end users, i.e. not available besides from the creator(s) of WindLDR - if you can make them provide a copy.

WindLDR runs terrible if youve never used it.

As this appears to be the only application that actually uses these files - there is no other to try with.
